# Dual citizen with different dates of birth on documents

Tags: us-citizens, dual-nationality, saudi-arabia, jordanian-citizens

I am a US/Jordanian citizen with two different dates of birth on my passports, due to an old mistake, which can't be fixed now.

I will be traveling to the US. I live in Saudi Arabia at the moment, as a resident, using my Jordanian passport. I can't book a direct flight to the US because airlines will need verification and I'm afraid that they'll ask to see my US passport and notice the two different dates of birth.

What can I do in this case? I thought of going to a country which doesn't require a visa for my two citizenships, such as Egypt. I would leave Saudi with my Jordanian passport and, as soon as I arrive in Egypt, enter with my US passport. Will that work? Would it raise questions? I would then fly from Egypt to the US.

Also, I have never been to the US since I became a US citizen. My passport is empty of stamps; will that cause a problem in the US or Egypt?

Comment: I suppose the first thing to ask is why can't the mistake be fixed?

Comment: Why do you have to show the airline your Jordanian passport? It seems to me that showing your US passport to the airline and to US immigration and your Jordanian passport to Saudi immigration might satisfy everybody.

Comment: Airlines here sometimes ask duals how did you enter the country as it doesn't appear on their systems. :D

Comment: Closing as OP has not answered the questions in comments.